# Setting up JAX RS in an existing non maven web application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to add jax rs with jersey to my webapplication, which already uses jax ws. It worked with plain text get and put but not with multipart form data.

I'm using

- **NetBeans 8.2**
- **JDK 8**
- **JAX WS 2.2.6**
- **Metro 2.0**

And following libraries for rest/jersey which I took from jersey homepage non maven user zip file:

```
aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar
hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jersey-client-2.25.1.jar
jersey-common-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-grizzly2-http-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-jdk-http-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-jetty-http-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-netty-http-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar
jersey-container-simple-http-2.25.1.jar
jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar
jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar
jersey-media-multipart-2.25.1.jar
jersey-netty-connector-2.25.1.jar
jersey-server-2.25.1.jar
jetty-continuation-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
jetty-http-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
mimepull-1.9.6.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

I added a ServiceResource class via the netbeans rest wizard. Which did not work properly i had to add a config class and manually added the service class to the config resources

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestConfig extends Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(ws.rest.UploadResource.class);
    }
}
```

So i could use the simple code generated from the wizard and received a text via get after i additionally added the servlet in the web.xml which looks like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest_let</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ws.rest.RestConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest_let</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

So I was able to access the service. But after adding another method to my resource:

```
@Path("upload")
public class UploadResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public UploadResource() {
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getText() {
        return "test";
    }


    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void putText(String content) {
    }
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("fup")
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) 
    {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("as expected").build();
    }
}
```

I always get this exception stack:

```
05-Jul-2017 09:35:23.059 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-22] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

05-Jul-2017 09:35:23.059 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-22] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet ws.rest.RestConfig
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there something wrong in the configuration? I didn't find a good tutorial for setting up rest without Maven so I tried on my own with lots of search on the net, which quite helped but now I'm stuck. It also vexes me because I already tried the same in a Maven project where it worked without a problem.